# using array print numbers inputed by user ignore duplicate numbers

Tags: java, arrays

example - input(10,20,30,10,50) output (10,20,30,50)

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Uni
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(in);
        int[]a=new int[5];       
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            out.println("Please type a number");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }      
        int temp;
        boolean flag = true;  
        while ( flag )
        {
            flag= false;
            for(int j=0;j<a.length-1;j++)
            {
                if ( a[ j ] > a[j+1] )
                {
                    temp = a[ j ];    
                    a[ j ] = a[ j+1 ];
                    a[ j+1 ] = temp;
                    flag = true;  
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(i==0){
            out.print(a[i]+" ");
            }else{
                if(a[i]!=a[i-1]){
                    out.print(a[i]+" ");
                }
            }       
        }
    }   
}
```

this is my code .. but i want to do it without doing the sorting ? using default method is highly discouraged !

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a Set?

Comment: to sort you can use `Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(a))`. If you then place the list's contents into a set you will also remove duplicates.

Comment: A few comments here: avoid using variables that don't explain what they are. `a` `flag` or `i` don't mean anything to us; explain what the problem is properly, not just "here's my input, I want this output"; search the internet before you ask. This problem has been solved a million times. I even commented on a post that asked the same thing; avoid calling you class `Uni`. It makes it even more obvious that you want us to solve your assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a write a function to check whether we are going to print the number or not? So that you don't need to sort the inputted array. Moreover, no builtin methods are used.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Uni {
    public static boolean isContain(int[] src, int end, int value) {
        int start;
        for (start = 0; start < end; start++) {
            if (src[start] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
        int[] a = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            out.println("Please type a number");
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                out.print(a[i] + " ");
            } else {
                if (!isContain(a, i, a[i])) {
                    out.print(a[i] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

> 10,20,30,10,50

Output:

> 10,20,30,50

Comment: thnx .. appriciate it mate :)

Comment: @MahirTazwar, you are welcome. You may read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Set...

```
Set<Integer> mySetNoDuplicates = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
for(Integer currentInt : mySetNoDuplicates){
    System.out.println(currentInt);
}
```